# 'string' file not found - Problem with Firebase Update and leveldb-library

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoa-touch, core-foundation, leveldb

For months now I can't update my Firebase, because all the new versions give me 2 errors:

- 'string' file not found
- could not build Objective-C module 'CoreFoundation'

Detailed message in Xcode:

> Compile MyAPIClient.swift ...

```
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/CoreFoundation.h"
        ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>
         ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:
#include <Block.h>
         ^ /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode - projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/table/Block.h:10:10: note: in file included from /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode - projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/table/Block.h:10:
#include "leveldb/iterator.h"
         ^ /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode - projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/include/leveldb/iterator.h:18:10: note: in file included from /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode - projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/include/leveldb/iterator.h:18:
#include "leveldb/slice.h"
         ^ /Users/Besfort/Desktop/Coding/Xcode - projects/0.1/Pods/leveldb-library/include/leveldb/slice.h:21:10: error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
         ^ <unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CoreFoundation'
```

Where is the core issue here? In my Swift file?
I am glad for any help.

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1916

Comment: It is more related to this:https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues/515,
but I have tried all the suggested solutions there (adding all files manually, etc.) but I get the same errors.

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2260#issuecomment-454470716